# For Loop after getline() doesn't execute

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline

I can enter input for the call to getline(cin, input, '\n'), but it is never ending. I can just keep giving input. I've tried without the for loop, and it accepts the input for getline() and then prints it. So my guess is it is a problem with the for loop. I have no compiler errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  int cat_appearances = 0;
  string l;
  cout << "Please enter a line of text: " << endl;
  getline(cin, l, '\n');

  for (i  = l.find("cat", 0); i != string::npos; i = l.find("cat", i)) {
    cat_appearances++;
    //move past the last discovered instance to
    //avoid finding same string again
    i++;
  }

  cout << "The word cat appears " << cat_appearances
       << " in the string " << '"' << l  << '"';
}
```

Comment: Simple debugging: (1) print the string in `l` before the loop; (2) print the value of `i`, or the value `i` would get: `cout << l.find("cat", 0) << "\n";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your compiler warnings on!

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
         for(i  = l.find( "cat", 0); i != string::npos; i = l.find("cat",i ))
                                       ^
```

The type of `std::string::npos` is implementation-defined, your compiler probably defines it as `std::size_t`, and on your platform `sizeof(unsigned int) < sizeof(std::size_t)`.

`std::string::npos` is defined as `std::string::size_type(-1)`, i.e. `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, a value which on your platform cannot be represented by an `unsigned int`.

Change `i` to

```
std::string::size_type i = 0;
```

<sup>(On a side note it's refreshing that you included a complete, compilable example!)</sup>